# Make Entity Framework use Contains instead of Like and explain 'ESCAPE ~'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a line of LINQ that im using in EF which is basically doing `myTable.Where(c => c.Contains('mystring'));`

This is the generated code:

```
SELECT TOP (300) 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[FKFishEntityID] AS [FKFishEntityID], 
[Extent1].[Fish] AS [Fish], 
[Extent1].[FishText] AS [FishText], 
[Extent1].[FishType] AS [FishType]
FROM [dbo].[Fish] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[FishText] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE '~'
```

My two questions are:

- How do I make it use CONTAINS(...) instead of LIKE? It seems that LIKE is very slow when the table is using full text indexing. Copying and pasting the query it takes 4 seconds to execute, but if I change LIKE to CONTAINS() it executes instantly.
- Why does it do ESCAPE '~' ? By copying + pasting this into SQL server, it executes around 4 times faster if I remove the 'ESCAPE' part.

Comment: Escaping is probably due to avoiding wildcard characters. Try put `mystring*` instead of `mystring` - in SQL Server it will be transfered as `mystring~*` probably - hence escape saying that tilde character before wildcard means it's not wildcard but exactly this character.

Comment: hmm, adding a * did not make a difference. I think it's connected to LIKE so if I can solve point 1 it might solve point 2

Comment: did not make a difference in what sense? Have you peeked parameter value in sql server (using for example profiler)? I know it's not solving your issue or helping - it's just tip on why escaping is there.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a profiler to examine the SQL. It always adds '~'. It's not as important as point 1 though.

Comment: @Pako what you mean is `%`.

Comment: Hah, of course I do. Completly forgot that wildcards there are different. Still - this is just about escape part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from the [entity framework blog]:[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2013/03/18/entity-framework-links-4.aspx)

> There is no native support for full-text search planned at the moment. You would need to use a raw SQL query.

Seems that the way to go is something like this:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext())
{
    var fishes = context.Fishes.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Fishes WHERE CONTAINS(FishText, @p0)", searchPhrase).ToList();
}
```

Comment: In the end I created a stored procedure to do a simple CONTAINS query.