# SQL generated by EntityFramework StartsWith() contains plan altering ESCAPE '~' (tilde)

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

Using EntityFramework, the clause `.OrderBy(x => x.Title.StartsWith("foo"))` results in the SQL `WHERE (Title LIKE 'foo%' ESCAPE '~')`.

Looking at the execution plan for the full query I see that I get a different plan (one making use of the column's non clustered index) when I remove the `ESCAPE '~'`.

Why is EF trying to escape a string which doesn't need it, and how can I make it stop?

Comment: Please post the full query exactly as intercepted by SQL Profiler. Something is not right here. The ESCAPE clause logically should not affect the optimizers decision. I also cannot reproduce: `SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name LIKE 'obj%' ESCAPE '~'`. Btw, the ESCAPE clause allows you to execute StartsWith("%") correctly. It is necessary.

Comment: @usr - [It can affect cardinality estimates](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/680257/optimization-problem-on-a-query-with-two-similar-like-clauses-one-with-a-variable) `We do not have support for precise cardinality estimation in the presence of user defined escape characters. So we probably get a poor estimate and a poor plan. We'll consider addressing this issue in a future release.`

Comment: Question was also answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935402/make-entity-framework-use-contains-instead-of-like-and-explain-escape

Comment: @MartinSmith good to know. On the other hand it seems like the estimator just ignored the ESCAPE clause. This should produce identical results for this exact query.

Comment: @usr They say they get a different plan though. The estimate of number of matching rows will make a difference if the choice is between a non covering index and lookups or a scan of a covering index.

Comment: @MartinSmith my understanding is that in their case the ESCAPE changed the meaning of the query. They actually escaped something. The estimator did probably not pick up the estimation because there is no histogram entry for `WC\[C`, just one for `WC[C`. That probably gave an estimation of 1 row. Anyway, a lot of guessing here.

Comment: @usr, ESCAPE '~' isn't needed in this particular case (it's "foo"). A fact which is available to EntityFramework at the moment it generates the superfluous SQL, I'd have thought.

Comment: @stovroz Probably it is just coded to always add the `ESCAPE` on the grounds that it is at worst (logically) redundant. Maybe the EF programmers didn't consider that it might affect cardinality estimates and plan choice. If they were aware of these issues they would use square bracket escaping instead.

Comment: @AndiKrusch, your linked item does not contain an answer to this question (or arguably its own).

Comment: @MartinSmith, thanks for your comments, I suspect no answer is going to offer much advance on these.

Comment: @usr - I've added a demo to my answer of the superfluous `ESCAPE` changing the plan. Though actually it gives *better* estimates in that case anyway!

Comment: possible duplicate of [linq to entities generated sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576803/linq-to-entities-generated-sql)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The superfluous `ESCAPE` can certainly alter cardinality estimates and give a different plan. Though funnily enough I found it make it more accurate rather than less in this test!

```
CREATE TABLE T
(
Title VARCHAR(50),
ID INT IDENTITY,
Filler char(1) NULL,
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (Title, ID)
)

INSERT INTO T
            (Title)
SELECT TOP 1000 CASE
                  WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) < 10 THEN 'food'
                  ELSE LEFT(NEWID(), 10)
                END
FROM   master..spt_values
```

Without `Escape`

```
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE (Title LIKE 'foo%')
```

[image]

With `Escape`

```
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE (Title LIKE 'foo%' ESCAPE '~')
```

[image]

Short of upgrading to a more recent version of EF or writing your own custom `DbProviderManifest` implementation I think you are out of luck in your attempt at removing `ESCAPE`.

Translating `String.StartsWith`, `String.EndsWith` and `String.Contains` to `LIKE` rather than `CHARINDEX` was [new in EF 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/10/22/new-features-in-entity-framework-impacting-providers.aspx)

Looking at the definition of `System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0` in reflector the relevant function seems to be (in `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderManifest`)

```
public override string EscapeLikeArgument(string argument)
{
    bool flag;
    EntityUtil.CheckArgumentNull<string>(argument, "argument");
    return EscapeLikeText(argument, true, out flag);
}
```

The signature for that method is

```
internal static string EscapeLikeText(string text, 
                                      bool alwaysEscapeEscapeChar, 
                                      out bool usedEscapeChar)
{

    usedEscapeChar = false;
    if (((!text.Contains("%") && !text.Contains("_")) && (!text.Contains("[") && !text.Contains("^"))) && (!alwaysEscapeEscapeChar || !text.Contains("~")))
    {
        return text;
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text.Length);
    foreach (char ch in text)
    {
        switch (ch)
        {
            case '%':
            case '_':
            case '[':
            case '^':
            case '~':
                builder.Append('~');
                usedEscapeChar = true;
                break;
        }
        builder.Append(ch);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

So it is just hardcoded to always use escape and the flag that is returned is ignored.

So that version of EF just appends the `ESCAPE '~'` to all `LIKE` queries.

This seems to be something that has been improved in the most recent code base.

The definition of [SqlFunctionCallHandler.TranslateConstantParameterForLike](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlGen/SqlFunctionCallHandler.cs) is

```
// <summary>
    // Function to translate the StartsWith, EndsWith and Contains canonical functions to LIKE expression in T-SQL
    // and also add the trailing ESCAPE '~' when escaping of the search string for the LIKE expression has occurred
    // </summary>
    private static void TranslateConstantParameterForLike(
        SqlGenerator sqlgen, DbExpression targetExpression, DbConstantExpression constSearchParamExpression, SqlBuilder result,
        bool insertPercentStart, bool insertPercentEnd)
    {
        result.Append(targetExpression.Accept(sqlgen));
        result.Append(" LIKE ");

        // If it's a DbConstantExpression then escape the search parameter if necessary.
        bool escapingOccurred;

        var searchParamBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (insertPercentStart)
        {
            searchParamBuilder.Append("%");
        }
        searchParamBuilder.Append(
            SqlProviderManifest.EscapeLikeText(constSearchParamExpression.Value as string, false, out escapingOccurred));
        if (insertPercentEnd)
        {
            searchParamBuilder.Append("%");
        }

        var escapedSearchParamExpression = constSearchParamExpression.ResultType.Constant(searchParamBuilder.ToString());
        result.Append(escapedSearchParamExpression.Accept(sqlgen));

        // If escaping did occur (special characters were found), then append the escape character used.
        if (escapingOccurred)
        {
            result.Append(" ESCAPE '" + SqlProviderManifest.LikeEscapeChar + "'");
        }
    }
```

[SqlProviderManifest.EscapeLikeText](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlProviderManifest.cs) is the same code as already shown. Note that it now passes `false` as the second parameter and uses the output parameter flag to only append the `ESCAPE` where necessary.

Comment: Do you have a blog, Martin?

Comment: @usr - No. I just write quite lengthy answers sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

As of Entity Framework 6.2, there is the added support for `.Like()` as part of `DbFunctions`.

So now you can do this:

```
var query = db.People.Where(p => DbFunctions.Like(p.Name, "w%"));
```

For more info: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/241