# linq to sql startwith performance indexed columns

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity

I use entity code first.
Indexed columns:

- SourceCatalogId
- Disabled
- CategoryPath

40 000 rows in the Table,

My problem is the query takes 40s!!

```
var result = DBContext.Set<SourceProduct>()
            .Include(x => x.SalesHistories, x => x.SourceCatalog)
            .Where(p => p.SourceCatalogId == 2)
            .where(p => p.Disabled == false)
            .where(x => x.CategoryPath.StartsWith("MyPath"))
            .orderby(x => x.ShortDesignation)
            .Skip(1)
            .Take(10)
            .toList();
```

SQL via sql profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10) 
[Project1].[SourceProductId] AS [SourceProductId], 
[Project1].[SourceSKU] AS [SourceSKU], 
[Project1].[SourceCatalogId] AS [SourceCatalogId], 
[Project1].[ManufacturerReference] AS [ManufacturerReference], 
[Project1].[Disabled] AS [Disabled], 
[Project1].[EAN] AS [EAN], 
[Project1].[ShortDesignation] AS [ShortDesignation], 
[Project1].[FullDesignation] AS [FullDesignation], 
[Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Project1].[Url] AS [Url], 
[Project1].[CategoryPath] AS [CategoryPath], 
[Project1].[Condition] AS [Condition], 
[Project1].[BuyingPriceHT] AS [BuyingPriceHT], 
[Project1].[ShippingPriceHT] AS [ShippingPriceHT], 
[Project1].[PublicSellingPriceHT] AS [PublicSellingPriceHT], 
[Project1].[PictureUrl1] AS [PictureUrl1], 
[Project1].[PictureUrl2] AS [PictureUrl2], 
[Project1].[PictureUrl3] AS [PictureUrl3], 
[Project1].[PictureUrl4] AS [PictureUrl4], 
[Project1].[Quantity] AS [Quantity], 
[Project1].[AddDate] AS [AddDate], 
[Project1].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate], 
[Project1].[Followers] AS [Followers]
FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[SourceProductId] AS [SourceProductId], [Project1].[SourceSKU] AS [SourceSKU], [Project1].[SourceCatalogId] AS [SourceCatalogId], [Project1].[ManufacturerReference] AS [ManufacturerReference], [Project1].[Disabled] AS [Disabled], [Project1].[EAN] AS [EAN], [Project1].[ShortDesignation] AS [ShortDesignation], [Project1].[FullDesignation] AS [FullDesignation], [Project1].[Description] AS [Description], [Project1].[Url] AS [Url], [Project1].[CategoryPath] AS [CategoryPath], [Project1].[Condition] AS [Condition], [Project1].[BuyingPriceHT] AS [BuyingPriceHT], [Project1].[ShippingPriceHT] AS [ShippingPriceHT], [Project1].[PublicSellingPriceHT] AS [PublicSellingPriceHT], [Project1].[PictureUrl1] AS [PictureUrl1], [Project1].[PictureUrl2] AS [PictureUrl2], [Project1].[PictureUrl3] AS [PictureUrl3], [Project1].[PictureUrl4] AS [PictureUrl4], [Project1].[Quantity] AS [Quantity], [Project1].[AddDate] AS [AddDate], [Project1].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate], [Project1].[Followers] AS [Followers], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[ShortDesignation] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[SourceProductId] AS [SourceProductId], 
        [Extent1].[SourceSKU] AS [SourceSKU], 
        [Extent1].[SourceCatalogId] AS [SourceCatalogId], 
        [Extent1].[ManufacturerReference] AS [ManufacturerReference], 
        [Extent1].[Disabled] AS [Disabled], 
        [Extent1].[EAN] AS [EAN], 
        [Extent1].[ShortDesignation] AS [ShortDesignation], 
        [Extent1].[FullDesignation] AS [FullDesignation], 
        [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
        [Extent1].[Url] AS [Url], 
        [Extent1].[CategoryPath] AS [CategoryPath], 
        [Extent1].[Condition] AS [Condition], 
        [Extent1].[BuyingPriceHT] AS [BuyingPriceHT], 
        [Extent1].[ShippingPriceHT] AS [ShippingPriceHT], 
        [Extent1].[PublicSellingPriceHT] AS [PublicSellingPriceHT], 
        [Extent1].[PictureUrl1] AS [PictureUrl1], 
        [Extent1].[PictureUrl2] AS [PictureUrl2], 
        [Extent1].[PictureUrl3] AS [PictureUrl3], 
        [Extent1].[PictureUrl4] AS [PictureUrl4], 
        [Extent1].[Quantity] AS [Quantity], 
        [Extent1].[AddDate] AS [AddDate], 
        [Extent1].[UpdateDate] AS [UpdateDate], 
        [Extent1].[Followers] AS [Followers]
        FROM [dbo].[SourceProducts] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[SourceCatalogId] = @p__linq__0) AND (0 = [Extent1].[Disabled]) AND ([Extent1].[CategoryPath] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N''~'')
    )  AS [Project1]
)  AS [Project1]
WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
ORDER BY [Project1].[ShortDesignation] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 bigint,@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=2,@p__linq__1=N'MyPath%'
```

In the last one before where clause, if I remove "**escape N''~''**" in:

```
WHERE ([Extent1].[SourceCatalogId] = @p__linq__0) AND (0 = [Extent1].[Disabled]) AND ([Extent1].[CategoryPath] LIKE @p__linq__1 ESCAPE N''~'')
```

the query takes 4s.

Is it normal ? Index uses ? How i can solve it with startWith ?

**EDIT**

Index attribut for categoryPath:

```
[Index("IX_SourceProduct_SourceCatalogId_Disabled_CategoryPath", 3), StringLength(400)]
    public string CategoryPath { get; set; }
```

**EDIT2**

OK i thing that I'm pretty close, I think the probleme is stored procedure.

```
string search = "julien";
            var list = db.Users.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(search));
            string query = list.ToString();
```

=>
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Name] LIKE @p__linq__0 **ESCAPE N'~'**

```
var list2 = db.Users.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("julien"));
            string query2 = list2.ToString();
```

=> 
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Name] LIKE N'julien%'

So if I use variable in the query in get a stored procedure, if I use const I get select.

In the stored procedure( generated by entity) makes appear **@p__linq__0** so add **ESCAPE N'~'** 
to avoid wildCaractere in the variable.

So now the question is simplier. How avoid query with variable ? it's possible ?
thanks

Comment: Just find this post, but don't understand if is there any solution ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496098/sql-generated-by-entityframework-startswith-contains-plan-altering-escape

Comment: are you using Full-Text index, or just normal indexing (which won't help you with partial-string matching)?

Comment: @Mashton I don't understand your question, but this is how I index with code first see the first EDIT

Comment: A Full-Text Index is used when you want to speed up string pattern matching, and isn't the same as normal indexing of a column. Indexing a column means it can find exact column matches quicker, but a FTI allows you to match on bits-of-those-strings. You will not be able to use your `linq.StartsWith` as FTI requires you use the sql command `CONTAINS`, which means you'll have to start calling stored procedures. But the speed increase is worth it. We went from 1m30s to <1s for a query we were doing. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Mashon thank you for your answer. Now it's clearer about full-text index. But I need just stratWith feature, and simple index should be enough (for contains feature you are right, full text will be needed). I Can check what I'm saying by when I remove "ESCAPE N''~''" in the sql query. The query is so fast and I see in sql profiler that I use the index. How Can I disable the escape feature in entity ? looks be closed to this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496098/sql-generated-by-entityframework-startswith-contains-plan-altering-escape

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So what you need to do here is take the value of a variable and use it as a constant in an `Expression` that you are generating.  This is actually quite possible.  What we'll need is an expression that accepts the parameter you want as the parameter of your real selector, as second parameter that is a placeholder for the constant value, and then the value that you want to be a constant.  We can then replace all instances of the parameter with the value of the constant, leaving just a function that maps the real parameter to the result:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> EmbedConstant
    <TSource, TResult, TConstant>(
    this Expression<Func<TSource, TConstant, TResult>> expression,
    TConstant constant)
{
    var body = expression.Body.Replace(
        expression.Parameters[1],
        Expression.Constant(constant));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(
        body, expression.Parameters[0]);
}
```

This relies on the following methods for replacing all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

This allows you to map this:

```
string search = "julien";
var list = db.Users.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(search));
string query = list.ToString();
```

Into this:

```
string search = "julien";
Expression<Func<User, string, bool>> predicate = 
    (item, searchTerm) => item.Name.StartsWith(searchTerm);
var list = db.Users.Where(predicate.EmbedConstant(search));
string query = list.ToString();
```

Comment: Amazing it works!!! One day spent on this... thank you so much. Can I offer to you a bear ;) (like we say thanks in france)

Comment: WTF? All that code just to include a Contains or StartWIth in a query??? and without this.. it would be sooo slow to execute.

Comment: how do I use this with LINQ to object? it gives me errors

Comment: trying to do this for linq to object  var results = (from I in db.mytable where i.mychildtable.col1.contains(search) select I).tolist());

Comment: It would be helpful to know where to put the above code.

Comment: Just tried this is EF 6.2.0 and still works like a charm!

Comment: If using a string constant, there will be a catch plan problem in sql. The query will be slow.