# convert variable to constant

Tags: c#, variables, constants

Can seems to be strange, but is there a way to declare or convert variable to constante something like :

```
string myVariable = "MyString";
const string myConstant = myVariable ;
```

I need this to answer to my problem:
[linq to sql startwith performance indexed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931201/linq-to-sql-startwith-performance-indexed-columns)

thanks

Comment: If a constant is truly constant, why would you need to set it to a variable?

Comment: "Can I set a constant to something that's not constant?"  Um... No.

Comment: `const` is compile time constant, It requires a compile time constant value. May be you could use a `readonly` field.

Comment: it's the opposite I want to convert variable to constant. To force entity generated sql select instead stored procedure. more details here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931201/linq-to-sql-startwith-performance-indexed-columns/25936537#25936537

Comment: Answer you've linked talks about expression trees, this post talks about source code... There is no direct connection between two - so this question is likely have nothing to do with what you really looking for... Maybe reading [Expression.Constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb349084%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) help on MSDN would be good starting point to ask new question. (You probably should just accept an answer to this one as I believe any real changes to this question will transform it into something completely different).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no  there is no way to do this for `Const`  Const values are burned directly into the call-site at compile time, Instead  you could make it `readonly` and assign it in the constructor

something like

```
string myVariable = "MyString";
readonly  string myConstant="test" ; 
public MyClass()
{ 
myConstant= myVariable ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot initialize a constant using the value of a variable.

Constants must be known at compile time, and the value of a variable is not known until runtime, making it conceptually impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise, change your first variable to a constant like below :

```
const string myVariable = "MyString";
const string myConstant = myVariable ;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a variable to initialize a field. The compiler may re-arrange the order these are initialized in, `myConstant` could be initialized first, in which case `myVariable` would be not be set.

Answer (score 0):

Constants cannot vary because they are not variables setting it to a variable would be varying it.  So the answer is no at least not at runtime.

Maybe you just want something that can't be set many places then readonly might work.

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7.aspx

```
public readonly string _myROString = "set once";
```

Comment: thanks but doesn't works on my case. The readonly is a variable in my code : readonly string search = "julien";  var list = db.Users.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(search));

Answer (score 0):

Well is not possible. But someone find an answer to my initial question without constant. thanks
[linq to sql startwith performance indexed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931201/linq-to-sql-startwith-performance-indexed-columns/25936537#25936537)

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not provide solution to the question posted; But may satisfy the requirement for some viewers who like to access string in a static manner  which should be appended with other strings,

```
public enum NameTypes
{
    First, Last
}

public static class UserDetails
{
    public static string NameText = "Name Info: " + NameTypes.First.ToString();
}
```