# LINQ inserts 'ESCAPE N'~' in query

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

When I examine the SQL query the Linq spits out, I noticed that it places a ESCAPE N'~' when doing a LIKE command.  How do I get rid of this?  It seems like the query takes twice as long with the ESCAPE is in the SQL.

Here is the LINQ

```
var SearchPhrase = "xyz";

var result = (from i in db.myTable
              where i.col1.contains(SearchPhrase)
              select i).toList();
```

When I look at the actual SQL it looks something like this:

```
   SELECT 
       [Extent1].Col1
   FROM myTable As [Extent1]
   WHERE [Extent1].Col1 LIKE @p__linq__3 ESCAPE N'~'
```

Comment: Does it add it when your argument to contains is `"xyz"`?  It should only add that if your input includes LIKE wildcard characters (`%, _, [, ], ^`)

Comment: Try changing the "xyz" in to a variable instead of a literal. The slow query performance may not be because of ESCAPE but because of the lack of proper query tuning related to your where clause.

Comment: xyz is a variable coming in to the method. But I place it about as a var in the code fo an example.

Comment: in studio manager, when I take out the ESCAPE and execute the query it execute 4x faster.

Comment: Can you add the actual query?

Comment: Please look into this SO article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931201/linq-to-sql-startwith-performance-indexed-columns this will definitely help

Comment: @magic-c0d3r: It's worth pointing out that the query window in SSMS automatically runs some additional commands that could potentially effect performance, such as telling the database to ignore statistics or use the query plan cache.

Comment: @rossisdead check out the comment above.. it seems like someone else got the same issue I did.

Comment: As @rossisdead mentioned make sure to understand differences between SSMS and your application - especially if hardcoding values. This article goes into great depth of different reasons. http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html#varparamreplace. I very much suspect that in general it shouldn't matter unless your databased has locked onto an inefficient query.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently,

```
var SearchPhrase = "xyz";
var result = (from I in db.myTabl
          where i.col1.contains(SearchPhrase)
          select I).toList();
```

will add ESCAPE N'~' in the underlying query.

However using a constant filter like the following, doesn't produce escape characters in the underlying query

```
var result = (from I in db.myTabl
          where i.col1.contains("xyz")
          select I).toList();
```

Which means, variable filters are escaped, while constants are not.

So, in this case, we need a variable to be used as a constant filter.

Using the following, shouldn't add any escape characters:

```
var SearchPhrase = "xyz";
var result = (from I in db.myTabl
          where SqlMethods.Like(i.col1, string.Format("%{0}%", SearchPhrase))
          select I).toList();
```

but this works only with LINQ to SQL.

The other alternative is to embed the variable value as a constant, which is done using the following as explained in the [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931201/linq-to-sql-startwith-performance-indexed-columns)

Comment: Apologies did not see the answer from @alanh

Comment: Will SO article work for LINQ to Entity? Seems like too much work to get something simple done.

Comment: Yes, the solution in the SO article will work for LINQ to Entity, it is not much work, just use those two static methods and add the expression in place of your where condition.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Sql use '`' as it's default escape character when doing like comparisons. It will only cause a problem if your string actually contains ~ characters.

Use [SqlMethods.Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340785%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to override this.

Comment: The SqlMethods.Like just works for Linq To Sql, does not for Linq To Entities

Answer (score -1):

If you use LINQ 2 Entities, use [`SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbSet.SqlQuery(System.String,System.Object[])) to remove the "~" character.

Just append the value to compare like an ordinary sql query.

For example:

```
var resultList = context.TableName.SqlQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE field LIKE '%" + fieldValue+ "%' ").ToList();
```

Comment: Beware of SQL injection.