# #Linq adds LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE '~'

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am working on a .Net application using Reverse POCO Generated Classes and trying to write a linq query which would retrieve values from the Microsoft Sql Server database  when a partial match is found from the users input.
ex:users input:12345
would yield the results
123456,
3434123456,
12345,
123456789001010,
etc

but using .contains in the linq query evaluates to a sql statement and adds something as shown below to the end of the statement.:
 LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE '~'}

This ESCAPE '~' adds 14-30secs of execution time and results in timeout issues.

It would be great if somebody could help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linq to sql startwith performance indexed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931201/linq-to-sql-startwith-performance-indexed-columns)

Comment: What database are you using?  I'm not seeing that with MS SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ inserts 'ESCAPE N'~' in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616733/linq-inserts-escape-n-in-query)

Comment: I saw Servy's answer on this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931201/linq-to-sql-startwith-performance-indexed-columns.
But unable to implement it .Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When using a variable in `.contains()` such as `.contains(inputVariable)`, the filter is escaped. You can either put a constant in the filter such as: `.contains('12345')` 
or you can use `SqlMethods.Like()` to perform the comparison instead of `.contains()`.

Here is a link to the docs for SqlMethods.Like: [SqlMethods.Like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340785(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hey Robyn,thanks for your reply.But I am currently using the Reverse POCO generator classes to connect to the SQL SERVER Database. So i am unable to use the SqlMethods.Like(). Any further help would be appreciated.