# Why Entity Framework is updating the Input value given, by preceded with '~' before '_' character

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am passing `'tim_bishop@hotmail.com'` as a input from client side, but in the back end EF is converting the value to `'tim~_bishop@hotmail.com'` (i.e., `~` is preceded before `_` ) before executing the command .
Can someone help me why EF is doing like this?

Comment: What do you mean `converting the value`? When does this happen?
 Entity framework is not doing this by default. It could be a million different things. Why do you think it's EF?

Comment: Please provide the complete query, along with its SQL translation if applicable.

Comment: Different Encoding maybe? Could be you are using a system still using old ISO code-pages instead of UTF8/UTF16.

Comment: Are you doing a LIKE in your SQL? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616733/linq-inserts-escape-n-in-query

Comment: Could also be some weird escape sequence/character.

Comment: @nbokmans I am thinking because I am using EF to retrive the data from DB. And I inherited **IDbCommandInterceptor** and used **ReaderExecuting** method to check what the value in DBCommand has, then I have seen that It is getting updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ inserts 'ESCAPE N'~' in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616733/linq-inserts-escape-n-in-query)

Comment: It is clear what is going on in this question. Voting to re-open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `_` is a special character used for matching a single character in a `LIKE` expression, EF is adding `~` as an escape character. The same thing is done for `%` character.

> I inherited `IDbCommandInterceptor` and used `ReaderExecuting` to check what the value in `DBCommand` has

If you intercept the SQL, the corresponding `LIKE` should look as follows:

```
WHERE ... AND t1.EmailField LIKE @p1 ESCAPE `~`
```

Comment: It is only my guess that you are using `Contains` on a `string`, which produces a `LIKE`. If this is not the case, please comment, I'll delete the answer.

Comment: Yes.. I am using **contains** in my Link to entity. So you are saying that, if we use % or _ in my input EF will add ~ and Escapes with ~.

Comment: @Satish Yes, that's right. Try using `%` to confirm. Do you know how to capture SQL generated by EF?