# Can't get contains(item) from hashset for where in Linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Update: so it looks like I need this: [linq to sql startwith performance indexed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931201/linq-to-sql-startwith-performance-indexed-columns) but it is unclear what files I need to put the code in.

I have the following base query:

```
resultsPeople = db.People
.Where(c => c.StudyDesign.Contains(item) && initialWithFiltersPeopleHashset.Contains(c.ID))
.Select(c => new { c.ID });
```

Now if I grab the results from a query that is direct like:

```
var resultsPeople = db.People
.Where(c => c.StudyDesign.Contains("Trial") && initialWithFiltersPeopleHashset.Contains(c.ID))
.Select(c => new { c.ID });
```

I get the right results back.

However, if I do something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchString, string[] filters)
{
    string[] searchTermArray = SearchString.Split(' ');
    var peopleList = new HashSet<string> { };
    foreach (var filter in filters) {
        peopleList.Add(filter);
    }
    var initialWithFiltersCohortHashset = new List<string>();
    var filtersNotNullCohorts = db.People
    .Join(db.OArea, c => c.ID, oa => oa.PersonID, (c, oa) => new { c = c, oa = oa })
    .Join(db.OFArea, oa => oa.oa.PersonID, ofa => ofa.PersonID, (oa, ofa) => new { oa = oa, ofa = ofa })
    .Join(db.Criteria, ofa => ofa.ofa.PersonID, iec => iec.PersonID, (ofa, iec) => new { ofa = ofa, iec = iec })
    .Join(db.OC, iec => iec.iec.PersonID, o => o.PersonID, (iec, o) => new { iec = iec, o = o })
    .Where(o => searchTermArray.Any(x => o.o.PO.Contains(x)) || searchTermArray.Any(x => o.iec.ofa.oa.oa.OT.Contains(x)) || o.iec.ofa.oa.oa.Category.Contains(SearchString) || searchTermArray.Any(x => o.iec.ofa.ofa.FArea.Contains(x)) || searchTermArray.Any(x => o.iec.iec.Criteria.Contains(x)))
    .Select(c => new { c.iec.ofa.oa.c.ID }).Distinct();

    foreach (var person in filtersNotNullCohorts)
    {
        initialWithFiltersCohortHashset.Add(person.ID.ToString());
        if (!noFilterCohortHashset.Contains(person.ID.ToString()))
        {
            noFilterCohortHashset.Add(person.ID.ToString());
        }
    }

        foreach (var item in peopleList)
        {
            var resultsPeople = db.People
            .Where(c => c.StudyDesign.Contains(item) && initialWithFiltersPeopleHashset.Contains(c.ID))
            .Select(c => new { c.ID });

            foreach (var person in resultsPeople)
            {

                studyDesignTempCohortHashset.Add(person.ID.ToString());
            }
        }
}
```

It doesn't return any results.  Why is this a problem?  If I print out the query, it looks like:

```
SELECT 1 AS [C1], [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID] FROM [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1] WHERE ([Extent1].[StudyDesign] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~') AND ([Extent1].[ID] IN (N'01301', N'02401', N'01312', N'01402', N'03201', N'00402', N'01303', N'01310', N'01304', N'02402', N'00201', N'01801', N'01101', N'02301', N'01307', N'03501', N'01001', N'02701', N'01306', N'01309', N'00401', N'01311', N'00203', N'03502'))
```

I'm still new to C# and linq, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Your `LINQ` query has not executed yet. Add `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` to get the deferred execution to run the query

Comment: So within the foreach ()?

Comment: Yeah, try that.

Comment: Neither worked.

Comment: Your question is not clear   U are iteration over something that totally different , please write full code!

Comment: You've already declared `item` in your first iterator..What is the actual code you're running?

Comment: Do you need the peoplelist or db.prople in the query ?

Comment: This is the full code.  I fixed the var item to person, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What is the peoplelist for ??

Comment: peoplelist is a set of filters sent.

Comment: Where do u use it in the linq query.

Comment: see edited code above.  It is sent as a parameter to the action.