# Why does this exception throw when calling a local variable in a where clause of a linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I want to execute this LINQ query, but since I've changed a hardcoded `5` to `firNr` (a local variable) in a `where` clause, I'm getting the following error:

```
System.AggregateException: "One or more errors occurred. (The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ArlArtikel>()
    .LeftJoin(
        inner: DbSet<LkoLagerkonto>(), 
        outerKeySelector: arl => arl.ArlArtikelnr, 
        innerKeySelector: lk => lk.LkoArtikelnr, 
        resultSelector: (arl, lk) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier0 = new { 
                arl = arl, 
                lkList = lkList
             }, 
            lk = lk
         })
    .LeftJoin(
        inner: DbSet<VlkVaLagerkontodispowerte>(), 
        outerKeySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier1.lk.LkoLagerkontolfdnr, 
        innerKeySelector: dw => dw.VlkLagerkontolfdnr, 
        resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier1, dw) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier2 = new { 
                <>h__TransparentIdentifier1 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier1, 
                dwList = dwList
             }, 
            dw = dw
         })
    .GroupJoin(
        inner: DbSet<PtpPreistabpo>(), 
        outerKeySelector: <>h__TransparentIdentifier3 => <>h__TransparentIdentifier3.<>h__TransparentIdentifier2.<>h__TransparentIdentifier1.<>h__TransparentIdentifier0.arl.ArlArtikelnr, 
        innerKeySelector: pt => pt.PtpArtikelnr, 
        resultSelector: (<>h__TransparentIdentifier3, ptList) => new { 
            <>h__TransparentIdentifier3 = <>h__TransparentIdentifier3, 
            ptList = ptList
         })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.)"
```

This is my code:

```cs
long firNr = 5;

var articles = from arl in context.ArlArtikels
    join lk in context.LkoLagerkontos
        on arl.ArlArtikelnr equals lk.LkoArtikelnr
        into lkList
    from lk in lkList.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join dw in context.VlkVaLagerkontodispowertes
        on lk.LkoLagerkontolfdnr equals dw.VlkLagerkontolfdnr into dwList
    from dw in dwList.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join pt in context.PtpPreistabpos
        on arl.ArlArtikelnr equals pt.PtpArtikelnr into ptList
    from pt in ptList.Where(a => a.PtpArlFirmennr == firNr && a.PtpIstnetto == 0).DefaultIfEmpty() // <--
    where arl.ArlFirmennr == firNr
    group new { arl, lk, dw, pt } by new
        { arl.ArlArtikelnr, lk.LkoArtikelnr, arl.ArlArtikelbez, pt.PtpPreis }
    into articleGroup
    select new ErpArticle() 
    {
        Id = articleGroup.Key.ArlArtikelnr,
        Title = articleGroup.Key.ArlArtikelbez,
        Quantity = (int?)articleGroup.Sum(g => g.dw.VlkVerfLagermenge),
        Price = articleGroup.Key.PtpPreis
    };

var res = await articles.ToListAsync();
```

I've found out that it works if I declare the variable as `const`, but I want to be able to change it. Can anybody explain why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it, please?

--- **EDIT** ---

With the answer of @Svyatoslav Danyliv I were able to write the working code now:

```
var articles = from arl in context.ArlArtikels
    join lk in context.LkoLagerkontos
        on arl.ArlArtikelnr equals lk.LkoArtikelnr
        into lkList
    from lk in lkList.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join dw in context.VlkVaLagerkontodispowertes
        on lk.LkoLagerkontolfdnr equals dw.VlkLagerkontolfdnr into dwList
    from dw in dwList.DefaultIfEmpty()
        // changes
    join pt in context.PtpPreistabpos
        .Where(pt => pt.PtpArlFirmennr == firNr && pt.PtpIstnetto == 0)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        on arl.ArlArtikelnr equals pt.PtpArtikelnr into ptList
    from pt in ptList.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where arl.ArlFirmennr == firNr
    group new { arl, lk, dw, pt } by new { arl.ArlArtikelnr, lk.LkoArtikelnr, arl.ArlArtikelbez, pt.PtpPreis }
    into articleGroup
    select new ErpArticle() {
        Id = articleGroup.Key.ArlArtikelnr,
        Title = articleGroup.Key.ArlArtikelbez,
        Quantity = (int?)articleGroup.Sum(g => g.dw.VlkVerfLagermenge),
        Price = articleGroup.Key.PtpPreis
    };
```

Comment: I have no idea why EF can't compute the value of the variable itself, but you can use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938275/1159478) to turn the variable into a constant in the expression while still having the variable be a variable in your code.  It shouldn't be needed, but it improves your existing workaround..

Comment: You have declared `firNir` as `long` - are you declaring it as `const long` when it works? Are you putting it in as `5L` and it works? What are the types of `PtpArlFirmennr` and `ArlFirmennr`?

Comment: Which EF Core do you use?

Comment: @NetMage Yes, if I'm declaring it as const long it works. I don't have to put in 5L, 5 is enough. PtpArlFirmennr and ArlFirmennr are both of type long.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm using EF Core 6.0.6

Comment: In your solution, the method `EmbedConst` returns `Expression<Func<TSource,TResult>>` but `Where` only accepts `Func<TSource,TResult>` for me. I tried it with `.Compile()` but I got an `AggregateException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core sill has limitstion in GroupJoin trnslating. It works only for simple LEFT JOIN, but it fails when query become complex.
I have rewritten your problematic part using [this technique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-where-clause):

```cs
var articles = from arl in context.ArlArtikels
    join lk in context.LkoLagerkontos
        on arl.ArlArtikelnr equals lk.LkoArtikelnr
        into lkList
    from lk in lkList.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join dw in context.VlkVaLagerkontodispowertes
        on lk.LkoLagerkontolfdnr equals dw.VlkLagerkontolfdnr into dwList
    from dw in dwList.DefaultIfEmpty()
    // changes
    from pt in context.PtpPreistabpos
        .Where(pt => arl.ArlArtikelnr == pt.PtpArtikelnr)
        .Where(pt => pt.PtpArlFirmennr == firNr && pt.PtpIstnetto == 0)
        .DefaultIfEmpty() // <--
    where arl.ArlFirmennr == firNr
    group new { arl, lk, dw, pt } by new
        { arl.ArlArtikelnr, lk.LkoArtikelnr, arl.ArlArtikelbez, pt.PtpPreis }
    into articleGroup
    select new ErpArticle() 
    {
        Id = articleGroup.Key.ArlArtikelnr,
        Title = articleGroup.Key.ArlArtikelbez,
        Quantity = (int?)articleGroup.Sum(g => g.dw.VlkVerfLagermenge),
        Price = articleGroup.Key.PtpPreis
    };
```

Comment: This helped really much. It didn't work exactly like this because `arl` could not get resolved in the first `where` clause, but it worked for the second one. I'm going to edit my original post and add the working code.

Comment: My fault, corrected code, Instead of `join` it should be `from`. Just typo.